# Using "would" instead of "will" in "How would be the weather like tomorrow?"

Tags: future-tense, will-would

> *How would be the weather like tomorrow?*

It can be very easily considered right in everyday English or informal style. Since *would* is always the past tense of the modal verb *will* —which is only used for future— so logically its past tense, *would*, should be used for the past time, not the future (tomorrow, in here) grammatically.

Hence, I think this sentence has grammar issue(s). And I would say: "*How **will** be the weather like tomorrow?*"

Comment: Where did you get this sentence? It's a very poor sentence, so knowing its source will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: I got it in a class offering by a non-native English speaker.

Comment: You should not take this class. This is a very bad sentence with multiple issues. We don't generally use "how" with this question, we use "what". The placement of "be" is wrong, we wouldn't use "would" at all. The standard form of this sentence is "What will the weather be like tomorrow?"

Comment: Thank you, I agree. I don't know how I didn't see the wrong placement of _be_!

Comment: You could have offered those comments as an answer so that I would be pleased of giving the accepted-reply vote to you as an appreciation.

Comment: Working on it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The sentence you've been told in your class is wrong. And it's wrong for more reasons than just "will" vs "would".

When asking about weather with will, we generally use "what", not "how".

There certainly are ways to use "how" but not with "will". An example is:

> How is the weather looking for tomorrow?

This is a more informal version of the question, though.

Additionally, the verb is too early in the sentence. It needs to be after "the weather".

So, after making all of these corrections, your final sentence (the standard way to ask what the weather's like in the future) is:

> What will the weather be like tomorrow?